# How to create different lighting components based on the values you have selected

Tags: lightning, ui

**This is my CMP file**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="index1" type="Integer" default="1"/>

    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate">S.No</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Field">Field</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Operator">Operator</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Value">Value</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <td >
                    1
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectId" class="slds-select" change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
                        <option value="null">-None-</option>
                        <option value="Name" >Name</option>
                        <option value="Sex__c">Sex</option>
                        <option value="birthdate__c">Birthdate</option>
                        <option value="Province__c">Province</option>
                        <option value="City__c">City</option>
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select">
                        <option value="null">-None-</option>
                        <option value="equal">equal</option>
                        <option value="not equal to">not equal to</option>
                        <option value="Less than">Less than</option>
                        <option value="greater or equal to">greater or equal to</option>
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <ui:inputText class="slds-input"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

**This is my JS file**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    },

    onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selected = component.find("selectId").get("v.value");
        console.log('get = ' + selected);
        if (selected === 'Sex__c') {

            $A.createComponent(
                "ui:inputText",
                {
                    "aura:id": "inpId",
                    "placeholder":"Enter Some Text",
                    "class": "slds-input"
                },
                function(element, status, errorMessage){
                    if (component.isValid() && status == 'SUCCESS'){

                       // .......
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
})
```

**The effect I want is**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After my efforts, I completed this function, if there is any incorrect place, you can leave a message to me.**

```
onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selected = component.find("selectId").get("v.value");
        console.log('get = ' + selected);

        if (selected === 'Name') {
            component.set("v.body",[]);
            $A.createComponent(
                "ui:inputText",
                {
                    "aura:id": "inpId",
                    "placeholder":"Enter Name",
                    "class": "slds-input"
                },
                function(newInp, status, errorMessage){
                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newInp);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }
                }
            );
        }else if(selected === 'Sex__c'){

            component.set("v.body",[]);
            var opts =  [
                            { "class": "optionClass", label: "None", value: "None", selected: "true"},
                            { "class": "optionClass", label: "1", value: "1" },
                            { "class": "optionClass", label: "2", value: "2" }
                        ];

            $A.createComponent(
                "ui:inputSelect",
                {
                    "aura:id": "inpId",
                    "class": "slds-select",
                    "options" : opts
                },
                function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
                    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                        var body = component.get("v.body");
                        body.push(newCmp);
                        component.set("v.body", body);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe `aura:if` could work here? You may have already looked into this option but[Here is the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if). It could be a bit messy if you have a lot of field types options you want to render dynamically but the alternative would probably be a lot of javascript.